What are the mainstream denominations (if any) of Christian atheists?
Christian atheism is the practice of following the teaching of the Christian bible, or Jesus, without believing in the existance of God or that Jesus is the son of God.
Do Christian atheists have denominations, and if so, what are those denominations?
I will accept either actual denominations of Christian atheists, or denominations of Christians who believe in God but who nevertheless have members who identify as Christian atheists, however, I am primarily interested in the former.

As a lifelong Christian I’ve never heard of even a single such denomination. There maybe individual churches out there that identify as atheistic - but certainly nothing mainstream. That said, I’m sure pretty much any church would welcome an atheist who was interested in attending services; just don’t expect to become a preacher or the like through them.

I wish the people downvoting this question would leave a comment saying why.

you cannot be a follower of Jesus without having faith and believing. Hence using the term Christian and atheist in the same title invalid.

Not really what you're looking for, but probably any major state church, be it the Catholic church in most of Europe, Lutheran in Scandinavia or Orthodox in Russia, has a number of people who at least formally associate themselves with that church while considering themselves atheists. I'm not aware of any of those denominations that condone Christian atheism though.

Your question is valid and does not deserve to be down-voted.  "Christian Atheism" exists and has been recognised in some places as a religion.  The expression, however, is a contradiction in terms.

If one changes the definition of Christian this can occur. Conversely if one changes the definition of atheist it also can occur

Every major Christian denomination---as well as every major non-Christian religion!---has its share of atheists who "inherited" the religion/church membership from their parents, who follow the customs and agree that the teachings (mostly) make sense, but who don't believe in the supernatural parts of their religion. So... I am confused by your question. Are you asking which Christian denomination has the highest percentage of church members who are non-believers?

Unitarian Universalism.  The Ready To Harvest YouTube channel has a good video on them.

Will you please explain what you mean by 'Christian atheists'?
I was brought up to believe that all 'Christians' believe in one god, while all 'atheists' by definition do not believe in any god.
What did I miss, please?

Contradiction in Terms The use of the terminology, "Christian atheist" is a gross contradiction of terms, and thus feckless, facetious, and inappropriate. To be a Christian it is by definition--and  in actual practice--necessary to believe in Jesus as God, as well  as the Father and Holy Spirit.  Atheism (Gk, "a-theism" = "no-god") has no part at all in Christianity religiously nor meaning linguistically. Therefore those who would claim this title are not speaking  logically nor consistently.  Denominations who accept these members are not traditional "Christian" in the since of the word.

Christian atheism is an ideology that embraces the teachings, narratives, symbols, practices, or communities associated with Christianity without accepting the literal existence of God. They can be found in many Protestant and Catholic denominations throughout North America and Europe. See this list:
This article explains four of the main common beliefs of Christian atheists:

[1] the assertion of the unreality of God for our age, including the understandings of God that have been a part of traditional Christian theology


[2] the insistence upon coming to grips with contemporary culture as a necessary feature of responsible theological work


[3] varying degrees and forms of alienation from the church as it is now constituted


[4] recognition of the centrality of the person of Jesus in theological reflection

With regard to denomination various surveys have come up with percentages of people in various countries who do not believe in God but identify as Catholic, Protestant or unaffiliated:

Of Americans who do not believe in God, 5% identified as Catholic, while 9% identified as Protestant and other Christian, according to the 2007 Pew Religious Landscape survey. Of Americans who identify as unaffiliated, including atheists and agnostics, 41% were raised Protestant and 28% were raised Catholic, according to the 2014 Pew Religious Landscape survey.


In the Netherlands, 42% of the members of the Protestant Church in the Netherlands (PKN) are nontheists. Non-belief among clergymen is not always seen as a problem. Some follow the tradition of "Christian non-realism", most famously expounded in the United Kingdom by Don Cupitt in the 1980s, which holds that God is a symbol or metaphor and that religious language is not matched by a transcendent reality. According to an investigation of 860 pastors in seven Dutch Protestant denominations, 1 in 6 clergy are either agnostic or atheist. In one of those denominations, the Remonstrants, the number of doubters was 42%.


A 2003 Harris Interactive survey found that 90% of self-identified Protestants in the United States believe in God and about 4% believe there is no God. In 2017, the WIN-Gallup International Association (WIN/GIA) poll found that Sweden, a majority Christian country, had second highest percentage (76%) of people who call themselves atheist or irreligious, after China. A substantial portion of Quakers are nontheist Quakers. Among British Quakers, 14.5% identified as atheists and 43% felt "unable to profess belief in God" in 2013.


Catholic atheists accept the culture, traditions, rituals and norms of Catholicism, but deny the existence of God. Miguel de Unamuno's 1930 novel San Manuel Bueno, Mártir depicts Catholic atheism. According to research in 2007, only 27% of Catholics in the Netherlands considered themselves theist; 55% were ietsist or agnostic deist and 17% were agnostic or atheist. Many Dutch people still affiliate with the term Catholic and use it within certain traditions as a basis of their cultural identity, rather than as a religious identity. The vast majority of the Dutch Catholic population is now largely irreligious in practice.

The expression “Christian Atheist” is a contradiction in terms because you simply cannot claim to be a Christian and follower of Christ if you deny the existence of God because Jesus came to earth as God incarnate. No God, no Christ, no Christianity.

I am very surprised to learn that "Catholic atheists" exist -- I was assuming this is mostly a Protestant thing.  Thank you for the answer.

I was also surprised, but it is the extent to which disbelief in our Creator God and belief in evolution has grown within Christianity that shocks me.

Until evidence turns up, this answer gives you several reasons why skepticism is warranted of the existence of the asked denomination (or a single church) of ideological Christian atheists.  (If I'm proven to be wrong, please notify me via a comment on this answer and I'll either update it or delete it )

From the Wikipedia article, which mentioned several theologians who profess the "Death of God" theology, it seems clear that the "Christianity" on offer here is an explicitly cultural Christianity that at best practice humanistic love without the grace of Jesus Christ, since Jesus Christ himself was a mere human who died normally and there was no living God who raised him from the dead.  Since there is no Being possessing Aseity and there is no Perfect human being of God (Jesus) who is ALIVE TODAY to love you from the heavenly realm, then this kind of Christianity has been robbed of these essentials that are part of orthodox Christianity:

That there is a Living Universal Church animated by the spirit of Christ (a.ka. the Holy Spirit).  So there is no True Fellowship in Christ, no Prince of Peace who could reconcile us with God's justice and who could heal our enmity with others.

There is living Creator God who will give us resurrection of the body after we die.  Dead God cannot resurrect anyone.  There is no true basis for Hope.

There is no God to worship, no Jesus for us to be grateful for.  There is no basis for true Joy.

There is no "engine" for Christians to give us new birth and to grace our spiritual life in our discipleship walk with Christ.  We are to become Jesus's branches, but if the vine is dead, there is no spiritual fruit.  There is no Love empowering us.


Orthodox Christianity not only teaches, but also points to the True source of Living Power (grace) to enable us to have true Fellowship, Peace, Hope, Joy, and Love.  Real Christians commune with this Living God and participate in being His sons & daughters within a visible church.  Atheist Christianity can at best teaches only ideas to practice without that power (grace), reducing it to secular humanism.
In theory, you can have a "collective of people practicing secular humanism" that is slapped a label "church", and a network of those collectives can be slapped a label "denomination".  But the raison d’être of an orthodox church is a visible collective of people who have experienced being called out from the world to be united with the living Christ.  Without this living relationship with God whom we talk to in prayer, there is no true church, reducing what you're looking for to a "church" in name only.  Dead God cannot be spoken to.  If prayers are meaningless, there is no church, only a social club.

I remember your question on Cultural Christianity - and you had some good answers! https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/100901/how-is-it-possible-to-be-a-cultural-christian-without-being-christian
